# Wordpress all links send me to home

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

My problem

all links in my site send me to home page like

[www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test) -> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Except page "wishlist" She takes me directly to her
I'm trying install and uninstall WordPress but same problem I think I have a problem in my plugins or PHP version I'm working in PHP v8.0.2

NS:"I have 39 plugins in site but don't know if They are the reason or not"

please help me it has been two weeks and still got the same problem.

Comment: Clear browser cache and update permalinks settings to default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't setup menu link properly, means in page link you gave custom link as "#". thats why all page linked to home page. plz check Appearance>Menu items.
For better help, kindly share your site link.